# All instances of maximum

Tags: python

I have a function that gets a set of data from a server, sorts and displays it

```
def load_data(dateStr):
    data = get_date(dateStr).splitlines()
    result = []
    for c in data:
        a = c.split(',')
        time = a[0]
        temp = float(a[1])
        solar = float(a[2])
        kwH = a[3:]
        i = 0
        while i < len(power):
            power[i] = int(power[i])
            i = i+1
        result.append((time, temp, solar, tuple(kwH)))
    return result
```

This is what the function returns when you enter in a particular date(only 3 entries out of a long list), the first number in each entry is the time, second is the temperature.

```
>>> load_data('20-01-2014')
[('05:00', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 34)), ('05:01', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 26)), ('05:02', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 35))
```

I need write a function to find the maximum temperature of a date, and show all of the times in the day that the maximum occurred. Something like this:

```
>>> data = load_data('07-10-2011')
>>> max_temp(data)
(18.9, ['13:08', '13:09', '13:10'])
```

How would I go about this? Or can you point me to anywhere that might have answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimal way to get *all* matching times for the maximum temperature is to simply loop over the values and track the maximum found *so far*:

```
def max_temp(data):
    maximum = float('-inf')
    times = []
    for entry in data:
        time, temp = entry[:2]
        if temp == maximum:
            times.append(time)
        elif temp > maximum:
            maximum = temp
            times = [time]
    return maximum, times
```

This loops over the data just *once*.

The convenient way (which is probably going to be close in performance anyway) is to use the `max()` function to find the maximum temperature first, then a list comprehension to return all times with that temperature:

```
def max_temp(data):
    maximum = max(data, key=lambda e: e[1])[1]
    return maximum, [e[0] for e in data if e[1] == maximum]
```

This loops twice over the data, but the `max()` loop is implemented mostly in C code.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it (this loops over the data twice):

```
>>> data = [('05:00', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 34)), ('05:01', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 26)), ('05:02', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 35))]
>>> max_temp = max(data, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
>>> max_temp
19.9
>>> result = [item for item in data if item[1] == max_temp]
>>> result
[('05:00', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 34)), ('05:01', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 26)), ('05:02', 19.9, 0.0, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 35))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_temp(data):
    maxt = max([d[1] for d in data])
    return (maxt, [d[0] for d in data if d[1] == maxt])
```